# JPA entity custom ordering

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA (Hibernate) entity shown below. There might be more than one rule and I need user of my app to be able to change order of rules. Therefore I introduced attribute **order**. When user decides that the particular rule should be the fifth rule on the list I need to set **order** to appropriate value and also change (recalculate) **order** of other entities influenced by this operation. I have some ideas (stored proc or many queries) how to do it but I like none one of them as they doesn't seem simple enough to me. Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue a simple elegant way? Many thans in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule")
public class RuleVO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "order", nullable = false)
    private Integer order;
}
```

Comment: Is this of use: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: Many thanks for the response but this unfortunately won't help me as the RuleVO entity isn't involved in OneToMany or ManyToMany relation.

Comment: what List then? if it isn't in an Entity.

Comment: Each RuleVO entity is created/updated individually. By list I meant calling an endpoint to give me a list of all rules stored in the database - JpaRepository.findAll().

Comment: So you're talking of a QUERY. Put an ORDER BY on the QUERY!

Comment: Being a hardcore java developer I would suggest to do this with code only. In java you will have the full control in your hand. You can either swap the order value or you can move all the values up or down as you wish. You can write optimized code which will serve your purpose and also it will not execute more than two database queries and it's pretty much acceptable. 
Writing a custom code will give you all power to make changes in your code anytime you want.

Cheers !!
Tushar,

Comment: @NeilStockton: No, I'm not asking how to use ORDER BY which I will surely use when fetching the list of rules. I'm asking about a mechanism how to maintain order (inserting or moving up/down) of rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no specific option in JPA for something like this. When the user changes the order, you're going to read all of the rules, set the order attribute and merge the results of all the rules back to the database. What else is there?